# Magento 1.7 Show Multiple Layered Navigation Filters on same page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am attempting to place the layered navigation in a strip in the header, as well as in the left sidebar. I am doing this by adding `<block type="catalog/layer_view" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>` into head block of my page.xml file. While this works, when I click on a filter I get an error that boils down to the fact that Magento does not like more than one filter:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:64:"You cannot define a correlation name 'device_idx' more than once";i:1;s:3844:"#0 /home/sitea/subdomains/casefun/trunk/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'device_idx.enti...', Array, NULL)
```

Followed by a stack trace.

How do I add the layered navigation to a theme more than once without it breaking when I select a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't display Layered Nav block more than once on one page. Every time the block is displayed, it applies filters to the Product collection.

Technically you can create a customization by extending standard Layered Nav block for your header or left placement and add a rule to **NOT** `applyFilters`, but this is not a simple task.

Comment: What about overwriting the controller that is applying the filters? Could a check be put in place (into the registry, for example) so if a filter has already been applied then do not apply it again? If that would work, what file would I need to alter?

Comment: As I said, it's not a controller, it's Block that does apply filters. If you're eager to try, you can move `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract` block to _local_ code pull, and alter `_initFilter` method. The **applying** part is line 91: `$this->_filter->apply($this->getRequest(), $this);`

Answer (score 1):

I had to overwrite Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute (in my local folder) to include a Singleton class: http://codepad.org/i2a1gL8i

This allowed only one version of each filter to be created.

A new problem was created, though. In the list of currently applied filters, each filter was appearing twice.

http://i.imm.io/Gk4w.png

The fix to this was a LOT simpler.

In `app/design/frontend/default/{theme}/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml` add the following check:

```
<?php $appliedFilters = array(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): //existing line ?>
<?php
  if(in_array(strtolower($_filter->getName()), $appliedFilters))
  {
    continue; 
  }
  $appliedFilters[] = strtolower($_filter->getName());
?>
```

If a filter with the same name has already been listed, then do not list any other filters with the same name.